# System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.this[string].get devolvió null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo el siguiente modelo con el que trato de pasar los datos de un formulario a una base de datos pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'
>
> System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.this[string].get devolvió null.

indicandome la linea Usuarios usu = new Usuarios

Este es el codigo del modelo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ProyectoDicar.Models;

namespace ProyectoDicar.Controllers
{
public class RegistarController : Controller
{
    // GET: Registar
    public ActionResult NewUser()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Alta(FormCollection collection)
    {
        gestionUsuario ma = new gestionUsuario();
        Usuarios usu = new Usuarios
        {
            Grado = collection ["grado"],
            nombre = collection["descripcion"],
            cedula = int.Parse(collection["precio"].ToString()),
            grupo = collection["grupo"],
            Pass = collection["pass"],
            rol = collection["rol"],
        };
        ma.Alta(usu);
        return RedirectToAction("/Register/NewUser");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: un breakpoint y verifica si la variable `collection["precio"]` está llegando

Comment: Si estaba alli el error pues este llegaba null muchas gracias

Comment: agrega la respuesta y mañana la marcas como aceptada, por cierto, bienvenido a SOes, revisa htttps://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio. Saludos :D

Comment: La solución estaba en que en el momento de verificar que la variable recibe un valor null constate que la variable collection["precio"] en realidad era collection["cedula"]